# Threading with Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I've written a Windows Forms application in C#. When I run a separate thread containing a method that toggles the invisibility of a panel on my form, it works the first time but not the second. Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: What language have you written your app in? Do you have some code to post?

Comment: Babel Fish is a helluva drug.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: Please do not invent new tags: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions/18879#18879

Comment: Translated:
Hello, i've written a windows forms application. When i run a separate thread containing a method that toggles the invisibility of a panel on my form, it works the first time but not the second. Why and how can i fix it? (would change the question itself but not enough rep)

Comment: @Modir: please show us the code that you use for toggling the panel visibility, as well as the code you use to fork a thread the first and second times.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, solved My Problem by follow Code :

```
Panel tmp = null;
switch (d.Person)
{
    case 1: tmp = backPic1;
        break;
    case 2: tmp = backPic2;
        break;
    case 3: tmp = backPic3;
        break;
}
if (InvokeRequired)
{
    tmp.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { tmp.Visible = true; }));
}
else
{
    tmp.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess be he UI code invoking from a background thread is. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but it sounds like you want to control the UI from a different thread, in which case you will need to synchronise the request. It's difficult to tell you how to do that without knowing what programming language you are using.